# Inject record in SqlDataSource

Tags: asp.net, sqldatasource

I would like suggestions on how to inject a record into my DropdownList to give an "All" option. Here is my code, data coming from the Northwind database.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRegion" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
    DataTextField="RegionDescription" DataValueField="RegionID" 
        AutoPostBack="True" onselectedindexchanged="ddlRegion_SelectedIndexChanged" />
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [RegionID], [RegionDescription] FROM [Region]" 
        ondatabinding="SqlDataSource1_Databinding">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I have tried the following but it does not add the item;

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack())
ddlRegion.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("All", "-1"));
```

I am thinking perhaps using the ondatabinding might be the right way to go but am not sure how to go about it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the All item in the ASPX, and then set AppendDataBoundItems=true and it will keep the statically defined items with the data bound items.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Unfortunately that same trick does not work for the DataList, it does not have AppendDataBoundItems property.

Answer (score 1):

Timbagas makes a good suggestion, another one is to use a stored procedure and do the  append there so the recordset that is returned includes the 'All' option, plus the rows that you want.